# Uploading image to imageshack using Java

Tags: java, base64, httpclient, image-uploading

I'm having trouble with the below code to upload an image to imageshack using Java. The response I get is that the http is refusing my connection. I think my issue is with how I'm giving the image file as I'm not sure if its supposed to be base64, byteArray, etc.

Any help would be great, thanks.

```
public String ImageShack (String imageDir, String myKey) {

    //set file
    BufferedImage image = null;
    File file = new File(imageDir);

    //Set namevalue pairs
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    try
    {
        image = ImageIO.read(file);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", byteArray);
        byte[] byteImage = byteArray.toByteArray();
        String dataImage = new Base64().encodeAsString(byteImage);

        //Assign name valued pars
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", myKey));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fileupload", dataImage));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("format", "json"));

        //Create HTTPClient and Client
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.imageshack.us/upload_api.php");

        //set entities
       httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        //Execute & get response
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        return response.toString();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
            return "Error: " + e.getMessage();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar problem, not specific to imageshack just a website, but here is the code from their solution:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("temp.jpg"));             
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", baos);
baos.flush();
Base64 base = new Base64(false);
String encodedImage = base.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray());
baos.close();
encodedImage = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(encodedImage, "ISO-8859-1");
request.setRequestBody(encodedImage);
```

Here is the [problem mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119553/base64-encoding-a-image-in-java-wrong-apparently-what-am-i-missing) above. [This article](http://www.myjeeva.com/2012/07/how-to-convert-image-to-string-and-string-to-image-in-java/) on Image/Base64 String conversion could also be helpful if that is the root of your issue.

Comment: I changed the code so its similar to yours above but it still isn't responding. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I would then recommend consulting the API documentation [here](http://code.google.com/p/imageshackapi/wiki/ImageshackAPI) or posting in their [help forum](http://code.google.com/p/imageshackapi/issues/list).